# How to define a Function in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I´m trying to create a program in fortran but when i created this function

```
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION ma(M)
    real(KIND=bigreal) uma, M
    uma = M*(1/1000)*(1/Na)
    ma = uma
    RETURN
    END FUNCTION ma
```

It says that the function has this error

```
23 |     real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION ma(M)
   |                                1
Error: Syntax error in data declaration at (1)
```

This is the complete code for better understanding of the problem

```
Program programa 
    integer, parameter :: bigreal = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(R=100)
    real(KIND=bigreal), PARAMETER:: T = 298 !En grados Kelvin
    real(KIND=bigreal), PARAMETER :: Na = 6.022E23 !Unidad mol
    real(KIND=bigreal), PARAMETER :: kb = 1.38E-23 !Unidad J/k
    real(KIND=bigreal), PARAMETER :: h = 6.626E-34 !Unidad J*s
    real(KIND=bigreal), PARAMETER :: pi = 3.1416   
    real(KIND=bigreal), PARAMETER :: R = 8.31446   
    real :: conf
    conf = S1
    
    PRINT *, 'El valor de la constante de Avogadro es:', h
    
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION ma(M)
    real(KIND=bigreal) :: uma
    real(KIND=bigreal), intent :: M
    uma = M*(1/1000)*(1/Na)
    ma = uma
    RETURN
    END FUNCTION ma
    

    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION VOL()
    real(KIND=bigreal) v
    v = (Na*kb*T)/100000.0
    VOL = v
    RETURN
    END 
    
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION TRAS(V1, M1)
    real(KIND=bigreal) V1, M1, q
    q = (((2.0*pi*M1*kb*t)/(h**2.0))**(1.5))*V1
    TRAS = q 
    RETURN 
    END FUNCTION 
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION Stras (Q1)
    real(KIND=bigreal) Q1, s 
    s=kb*LOG(Q1*EXP(1.5))
    Stras = s 
    RETURN

    END FUNCTION Stras
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION Gtras (Q2)
    real(KIND=bigreal) g, Q2
    g = kb*T*LOG(EXP(1.0)/Q2)
    Gtras = g
    RETURN
    END FUNCTION Gtras
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION U ()
    real(KIND=bigreal) u1
    u1 = kb*T*1.5
    U = u1
    RETURN
    END FUNCTION U
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION Sele (deg1)
    real(KIND=bigreal) sel 
    sel = kb*LOG(deg1)
    Sele = sel
    RETURN
    END FUNCTION Sele
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION Gele (deg1)
    real(KIND=bigreal) gel 
    gel = kb*T*LOG(EXP(1.0)/deg1)
    Gele = gel
    RETURN
    END FUNCTION Gele
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION Scombi(vtras, deg2)
    real(KIND=bigreal) scomb, vtras, deg2
    scomb = (2.5*R) + R*LOG(vtras*(deg2/Na))
    Scombi = scomb 
    RETURN
    END FUNCTION Scombi
    real(KIND=bigreal) FUNCTION Gcombi(vtras1, deg3)
    real(KIND=bigreal) gcomb, vtras1, deg3
    gcomb = -kb*T*LOG(vtras*deg2)
    Gcombi = gcomb 
    RETURN
    END FUNCTION Gcombi
    
   
    
    
end Program programa
```

Which I decided to use because the values that I have to work with are pretty small

I tried google the error but nothing seems useful

Comment: Please show a _complete_ example, such as explained in [mre].

Comment: There are many guesses we can make, such as you are missing `contains`, but without context they will just be guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  It seems that I was missing a `contains` between the print and the first function.

Comment: Well, I don't think your number is going to be very big when it has done this line: ```uma = M*(1/1000)*(1/Na)```